# Real time Tracking System with php

Tags: php, ajax

I am working on my simple ecommerce website, when i visited Freelancer.com i noticed a very nice feature but i unfortunately i do not know what it is technically called and that is why i find it hard to locate a decant tutorial on the matter.

Freelancer has a feature that allows project owner to see how many users are looking at his project in real time, the numbers keep changing in a real time, i know that Ajax allows database to be retrieved with out refreshing the page, however this to happen a button has to be clicked. In freelancer this numbers change with out any interaction with the system.

So how does this works, can someone point me out to a nice tutorial that shows how can implement this feature on my site, or what is it called so that I can look for it. I would also appreciate a nice tutorial on how can I develop a php visitor tracking system. And that is why I need to make my back end track users in real time I don’t need to refresh my page every time in order to see the changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can for example get dynamically the number of viewers from a php file in the server through a javascript function that is called periodically in your webpage.

```
<script>
function RequestNumberOfViewers(file){
     $.get(file, function(data) {
          PrintViewers(data); //Changes the html content of a div updating a number for example.
     });
};

setInterval(function(){RequestNumberOfViewers(viewers.php)}, 5000); //Calls the function periodically
</script>
```